# What Are The Parts Of This Sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Here is the sentence:

> Total bed rest is not necessary, just rest for the injured part of the body.

I am trying to diagram this sentence but I don't know how "just rest for the injured part of the body" fits into the sentence.  Does it modify a word somewhere in the sentence?  What is the functionality of that part of the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a parallel structure whose second clause is lacking a piece. Try to add a possibly omitted [**what's required is**] after the comma and the sentence will sound less rickety.

> Total bed rest is not necessary, [**what's required is**] just rest for the injured part of the body.

Comment: Close. Actually it's two sentences: _Total bed rest is not required_, and _Rest for the injured part of the body is required._ Conjunction reduction deletes the verb phrase in the second one, leaving only the subject, which is linked with the subject of the first negative sentence as a comparison. The _just_ is the comparison -- one is less than the other.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence breaks down as below.  Note that *rest* is a noun in both parts of sentence:

Total bed **rest** (the subject for this clause) is not necessary, just **rest** (the subject for this clause) for the injured part of the body = One kind of rest is not needed, but another kind of rest is needed.

As two sentences, we would have: Total bed rest is not necessary. However, partial rest (for the injured part *alone*) is necessary.

Since *rest* is not used as a verb, the sentence is not suggesting that you *just rest*, to relax the injury.